# Unable to deploy openapi spec with apiKey auth using kin-openapi

Tags: go, security, openapi

My openapi spec (below) is throwing the error "security requirements failed" when used with `kin-openapi` for my go application when trying to create routers. This is my spec:

```
openapi: '3.0.0'
info:
  version: '1.0.0'
  title: 'My application'
servers:
  - url: https://example.mydomain.com/v1
security:
  - ApiKeyAuth: []
components:
  securitySchemes:
    ApiKeyAuth:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: X-API-Key
paths:
  "/testData":
  get:
    summary: Obtains test data.
    operationId: getTestData
    responses:
      200:
        description: Successful response.
        content:
          text/plain:
            schema:
              type: string
```

I am following https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/api-keys/ and using kin-openapi. I have not defined it on a path level, which is not required. I am not sure why I am getting the error which seems to be returned from `kin-openapi` library when it is trying to `validateSecurityRequirements`, however from the docs I have followed it.

Comment: Not sure if related, but the indentation after the `get:` line is off. The remaining lines must be _inside_ the `get:` key (i.e. indented to the right of it). If it's not a copy-paste error and is the actual indentation in your spec, fix it and see if it helps.

Comment: Oops apologies, it seems to have been a copy paste error with indentation! Have fixed. Thanks for pointing it out